# C# - Select Rown in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, row

I am currently working on my datagridview which is being populated by a stored procedure's query from the database. My question is how can I select the whole row even though I only click one cell?

Example, there are four columns returned by the stored procedure. So basically the datagridview will present to me data in four columns. If I select row 2 of column 3, is it possible that the action will not only highlight the row2 column 3 but the whole row 2?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode.aspx) of your datagridview to `FullRowSelect`:

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
```

Comment: right thanks :) but, how will I get the selected index of the row i selected? thanks :)

Comment: on the click event from the row, it returns in the parameter "e" has property called "RowIndex" or something like that, sorry I don't know for sure cause I am away from any VS right now. But follow this glue I think you gonna find that.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Index

DataGridView1.Refresh()

DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Cells(1)

DataGridView1.Rows(counter).Selected = True
```

More: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/47e9c3ef-a8de-48c9-8e0d-4f3fdd34517e/

Answer (score 0):

There is a [DataGridView.SelectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6w9028.aspx) property you can set to fullrowselect.